# How to transform data from rows based on a specific column to another data structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a result set which I want to "flatten" by the `Service` column.
Example will explain it best:

Given this result set (Lets call it `request`):

```
---------------------------------------
| Id |    Service   |  C1 | ... | Cn  |
--------------------------------------|
|  1 |       A      |  5  |     | 3   |
--------------------------------------|
|  1 |       B      |  2  |     | 1   |
--------------------------------------|
|  2 |       A      |  9  |     | 4   |
--------------------------------------
```

I want to get this one:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id |  ServiceA_C1 | ... | ServiceA_Cn |ServiceB_C1 | ... | ServiceB_C2n |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 |       5       | ... |      3      |     2      | ... |       1      |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 |       9       | ... |      4      |    NULL    | ... |      NULL    |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Final desired outcome:**

- Each Id (which had multiple values now have one row)
- Each distinct value of service will have `n` columns in the final result set

**Current solution (which works, but super long and not efficient):**

```
SELECT A.C1 AS ServiceA_C1, ..,A.Cn AS ServiceA_Cn,B.C1 AS ServiceB_C1, ..,B.Cn AS ServiceB_Cn  
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM request
      WHERE Service = 'A') AS A
    JOIN
      (SELECT *
      FROM request
      WHERE Service = 'B') AS B
    ON A.Id = B.Id
```

**Notes:** 
Number of services is about 10 (#distinct values in `Service` column), 
This is a generic phrasing of the problem itself.

I know SQL manipulations like pivot, unpivot, cross apply, joins  etc, and still this problem annoys me because I didn't found something tricky to instantly solve this. I would be happy to know that one of this methods solves this and I missed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unpivot/pivot to get the result that you want.  There are a few different ways that you can get the result, if you have a limited number of values then you can hard-code the query but if you have an unknown number of values then you will need to use dynamic SQL.

The UNPIVOT process will convert the multiple columns of `c1`, etc` into multiple rows. Once the data is in the multiple rows then you can easily apply the PIVOT function.  You can use the unpivot function or CROSS APPLY to convert the data from multiple columns:

```
select id,
  col = 'Service'+Service+'_'+col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
  value
from
(
  select id, service, c1, cn
    , row_number() over(partition by id
                        order by service) seq
  from yourtable
) t
cross apply
(
  select 'c1', c1 union all
  select 'cn', cn
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72ab3/14). The cross apply will convert your data into the format:

```
| ID |           COL | VALUE |
|  1 | ServiceA_c1_1 |     5 |
|  1 | ServiceA_cn_1 |     3 |
|  1 | ServiceB_c1_2 |     2 |
|  1 | ServiceB_cn_2 |     1 |
|  2 | ServiceA_c1_1 |     9 |
|  2 | ServiceA_cn_1 |     4 |
```

Once the data is in this format you can apply PIVOT:

```
select id, ServiceA_c1_1, ServiceA_cn_1,
  ServiceB_c1_2, ServiceB_cn_2
from
(
  select id,
    col = 'Service'+Service+'_'+col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    value
  from
  (
    select id, service, c1, cn
      , row_number() over(partition by id
                          order by service) seq
    from yourtable
  ) t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'c1', c1 union all
    select 'cn', cn
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (ServiceA_c1_1, ServiceA_cn_1,
              ServiceB_c1_2, ServiceB_cn_2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72ab3/16).

Then if you have an unknown number of values, you can convert the above query to dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Service'+Service+'_'+col+'_'+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select service, 
                        row_number() over(partition by id
                                          order by service) seq
                      from yourtable 
                    )d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'c1', 1 union all
                      select 'cn', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, Service, col, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select id,
                col = ''Service''+Service+''_''+col+''_''+cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                value
              from
              (
                select id, service, c1, cn
                  , row_number() over(partition by id
                                      order by service) seq
                from yourtable
              ) t
              cross apply
              (
                select ''c1'', c1 union all
                select ''cn'', cn
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72ab3/17).  Both will give a result:

```
| ID | SERVICEA_C1_1 | SERVICEA_CN_1 | SERVICEB_C1_2 | SERVICEB_CN_2 |
|  1 |             5 |             3 |             2 |             1 |
|  2 |             9 |             4 |        (null) |        (null) |
```