# Display all item tags

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a web application similar to a blogging software.

And want to display the blog post categorized by tags, the output to client should be:

```
--PostID 1--
--PostContent 1--
--Tags : tag1 , tag2 --

--PostID 2--
--PostContent 2--
--Tags : tag1 , tag2, tag3 --

--PostID 3--
--PostContent 3--
--Tags : tag3 , tag4--
```

So i using a Query like :

`Select PostTitle, PostContent from tblBlogPost ...`

But the tags are located in a new table with below structure :

```
PostID   PostTag
1        tag1
1        tag2
2        tag1
2        tag2
2        tag3
3        tag3
3        tag4
```

So how do i include the tag list into my query ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transform data from rows based on a specific column to another data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144535/how-to-transform-data-from-rows-based-on-a-specific-column-to-another-data-struc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot`, you can see a detailed answer here: 
[How to transform data from rows based on a specific column to another data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144535/how-to-transform-data-from-rows-based-on-a-specific-column-to-another-data-struc)

You will just have to use this code for each one of your `PostID` (unless you don't care having NULL values for some tags --> then you can do it in one query):

An example for PostID = 2:

```
select PostID, Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
from
(
  select id,
    col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    value
  from
  (
    select PostID, PostTag
      , row_number() over(partition by PostID
                          order by PostID) seq
    WHERE PostId = 2
    from yourtable
  ) t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Tag', PostTag 
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (Tag1, Tag2, Tag3)
) piv;
```

Comment: What happen if i have unlimited tag ?

Comment: It's still not an issue, you can see the answer in the post I attached, it has a part where it describe how you can do it without assuming any number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you can parse XML or xslt in your application I would consider using sqlxml. Something like this query

```
select
    top 1 Post,
    (
    select 
        Tag

    from Posts_Tags bb
    where aa.Post= bb.Post
for xml raw ('Tags'), type
    ) as users
From Posts aa
for xml raw('Posts'), type
```

will return something like this;

```
<Posts Post="Post1">
  <Tags>
    <Tags Tag="A" />
    <Tags Tag="B" />
    <Tags Tag="C" />
  </Tags>
</PostTags>
```