# Transposing Two Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SQL. I looked forever on this site for an answer to this, but I couldn't. I have data that looks like this:

```
Code |  Name  
A    |  John  
A    |  Bob  
A    |  Chris  
B    |  James  
B    |  Jen  
B    |  Teddy
```

I would like it to build a query that would result in this:

```
Code | Name | Name2 | Name3  
A    | John |  Bob  | Chris  
B    | James|  Jen  | Teddy
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: A little more clarification would help

Comment: Have you looked at `UNPIVOT`?

Comment: Sam, I've just banged my head against the wall with PIVOT command for four hours now. My queries result in the right format but the Name fields end up as NULL.

Comment: I asked a very similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144535/how-to-transform-data-from-rows-based-on-a-specific-column-to-another-data-struc. The question isn't exactly the same but the solution contains what you need.

Comment: For reference, this is the query I'm currently using that results in the nulls:

select * 
from 
(
  select Code, Name
  from tabe
) a
pivot
(
  max(Name)
  for [Name] in ([Name], [Name2], [Name3])
) piv

Comment: Do you actually need multiple columns or a single column with separated values would be fine e.g. one field holding "John | Bob | Chris" string?

Comment: I need the columns as well.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `PIVOT`.  However, a `PIVOT` is intended to be used on 'category' values, meaning you have the same set of categories per group.  You don't have anything that is similar between each group, like a 'name index' or anything.  So you can't identify the `PIVOT` columns properly.

The simple solution is to manufacture a category for each name in the group, like `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3`, etc. that you can `PIVOT` on.  This can be done with a `ROW_NUMBER()` clause like this:

```
select Code,
  'Name' + cast(
      row_number() over (partition by Code order by code)
  as varchar(10)) as NameType,
  Name
from table1
```

Which produces results that look like this:

```
| CODE | NAMETYPE |  NAME |
|------|----------|-------|
|    A |    Name1 |  John |
|    A |    Name2 |   Bob |
|    A |    Name3 | Chris |
|    B |    Name1 | James |
|    B |    Name2 |   Jen |
|    B |    Name3 | Teddy |
```

Now you have something shared between groups to `PIVOT` on - the `NAMETYPE` column:

```
select * from ( 
  select Code,
    'Name' + cast(
        row_number() over (partition by Code order by code)
    as varchar(10)) as NameType,
    Name
  from table1
) a
pivot ( max(Name) for [NameType] in ([Name1], [Name2], [Name3]) ) piv
```

This produces the desired results:

```
| CODE | NAME1 | NAME2 | NAME3 |
|------|-------|-------|-------|
|    A |  John |   Bob | Chris |
|    B | James |   Jen | Teddy |
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21499/7